# Can't Query Custom Table Using $wpdb Method

Tags: php, mysql

I created a custom table for my Wordpress site using Sequel Pro. I am then trying to query the table from Wordpress PHP file using $wpdb method. While I am able to run a successful query using the standard Wordpress tables, it does not work for the custom tables I create.

So this one works:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "
    SELECT * 
    FROM  $wpdb->users
        WHERE ID = '1'
" );

foreach ( $result as $page )
{
   echo $page->user_email.'<br/>';
   echo $page->user_nicename.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

This one doesn't:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$result = $wpdb->get_results ( "
    SELECT * 
    FROM  $wpdb->prefix.'my_employees'
        WHERE ID = 1
" );

foreach ( $result as $page )
{
   echo $page->user_login.'<br/>';
   echo $page->user_nicename.'<br/>';
}
?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a double quoted string, so your table name literally contains `.'my_employees'`

Try the curly syntax instead:

```
"SELECT * 
FROM {$wpdb->prefix}my_employees
WHERE ID = 1
";
```